# Access UIButtons like buttonName+i

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton

I'm trying to change the properties of various UIButton that I have declared as follows:

> UIButton * button1; UIButton *
>   button2; ....

It's possible to access them in a similar way to this?

> [button+i setTitle:@"button"
>   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

The variable "i" would be an integer to distinguish one from button from another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the tag property of UIButton, which is an integer

EDIT to show tag property

```
UIButton* myButton .... // whichever way your button is init'd
// set the tag
myButton.tag = 2; // or i or whatever way you set it the property is an int
// get the tag
int y = myButton.tag; // set y to the tag value of the button
```

its that easy

Comment: I second this, +1. It's cleaner and the lookout is also pretty darn fast ;)

Comment: I've never used the tags property, can you post an example? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have lots and lots of button?

Okay, the immediate best way I can think of is something I have put into practice when I had something like 30+ buttons on a screen (it was a calendar).

I created an array into which I put the button then accessed them like this (or something like this)

```
for (UIButton* b in myBigArrayOfButtons) {
    [b setTitle:@"button" for State:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```